# VB .net Context/ToolStripMenu at runtime

Tags: vb.net, menu, contextmenu, addhandler, toolstripmenu

I have a ContextMenu like in [this](http://s24.postimg.org/8hdnow3ol/stov.png) picture. Now i want to add where it says ".rtf" more MenuItems at runtime. I cant seem to make it...

```
Dim myContextMenu As ContextMenuStrip = Form1.mnuOptions
Dim myMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = myContextMenu.Items("SendTo")
Dim mySubMenuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem = myMenuItem.DropDownItems("File").SUBITEMS
```

This is how i imagine doing it, but it does not work of course because there is no ".subitems". What does it take to accomplish such an easy job?

And how can I set AddHandlers for each SubItem to a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'File' is the name of the menu item with that text, you can access it directly by it's name, and add the dropdown item to its collection:

```
File.DropDownItems.Add("Pdf")
```

One of the Add overloads allows you to indicate which event handler the click will fire.